# How to space strings in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to create a dynamic list using the following code:

```
const permissions: string[] = []

Object.keys(userPerms).forEach((key) => {
  permissions.push(`${capitalise(key)} ${userPerms[key] ? '' : ''}`)
})
```

The output I want:

```
Send Messages   
Join Call       
Send Emojis
```

The output I am getting with my current code:

```
Send Messages 
Join Call 
Send Emojis
```

Comment: What about the code you've written leads you to expect that output?

Comment: Where is the result displayed? The basic idea would be to work out the longest `key` and use [`String.prototype.padEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd) to make up the difference for shorter strings. If you're displaying this in HTML though, you can probably just use CSS

Comment: Are you trying to align the output during the list insertion using string concatenation?

Comment: I have edited my question to make what I am asking for clearer.

Comment: @Phil I am outputting this on a Discord message embed, how would I work out the longest `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this snippet. You need to calculate the maximum length of the permission string key. After that add spaces according to that maximum length. If you want to do it by hand.

```js
let userPerms = {
  "Send Messages": true,
  "Join Call": false,
  "Send Emojis": true,
};

// Find maximum lenght
let max = 0;
Object.keys(userPerms).forEach((key) => {
  if (key.length > max) {
    max = key.length;
  }
});

// Give additional 2 spaces
max += 2;

const permissions = []
Object.keys(userPerms).forEach((key) => {
  permissions.push(key.concat(' '.repeat(max - key.length)) + (userPerms[key] ? '' : ''))
})

console.log(permissions);
```

More elegant solution will be:

```js
let userPerms = {
  "Send Messages": true,
  "Join Call": false,
  "Send Emojis": true,
};
const permissions = []

// Find maximum lenght
let max = Object.keys(userPerms).sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0].length + 2 // space between;
// Add to array
Object.keys(userPerms).forEach((key) => {
  permissions.push(key.padEnd(max) + (userPerms[key] ? '' : ''))
});

console.log(permissions);
```